# Off-frame animation cycle?

Tags: animation, modifiers

Quick question:

Is it possible to cycle an animation in Blender in such a way that it does not repeat on an exact frame, but so that it is slightly off?

Here is an example to clarify what I'm on about. I want to tell Blender:

**"Repeat the animation 30 times for the duration of 1000 frames (= animation repeats every 33.3333333.... frames)"**

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.
Create the **Action** you want to repeat in the **Dopesheet**.

[image: action in dopesheet]

For clarity, my action is going to be 9.1 frames long and going to repeated 10 times.
Note, that the the length of 9.1 will come from the start and and frames: 1 to 10.1.

```
endframe - startframe = duration
10.1     -         1  = 9.1
```

1. Go to the NLA Editor. [image: nla]
2. Press the Push Action Down button. [image]
3. Go to the properties panel in the NLA editor and to the *Action Clip* section.
4. Set the *start frame* to your start frame (1)
5. Set the *end frame* to your end frame (10.1)
6. Set the *repeat* property to the numer of times, you want to repeat the action clip.

[image: action clip nla]

The Action will no be repeat with an offset of 0.1 frames.

Comment: I will try that, thank you for the quick and detailed reply!